# AWS CLI: aws sync between 2 different s3 providers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Does anybody have a solution to sync a bucket between 2 different s3 providers?

For example one is Amazon S3, second is Wasabi S3?

That involves 2 different endpoints and 2 different sets of credentials.

Preferable without storage data locally first, talking about 1+ million files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would not be possible.

In Amazon S3, it is possible to copy directly between two buckets, even in different regions, because the S3 services in each region communicate with each other.

This wouldn't be possible with a non-Amazon service.

Therefore, your best bet would be to launch an EC2 instance, use `aws s3 sync` to download the files, then use `aws s3 sync` (with a different endpoint & credentials) to connect to Wasabi.

It is *possible* that the S3-compatible providers might offer an easier method, but it appears that Wasabi recommends the 'download and copy' method: [How do I copy files from AWS S3 to Wasabi? – Wasabi Knowledge Base](https://wasabi-support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000258332-How-do-I-copy-files-from-AWS-S3-to-Wasabi-)

Comment: Thanks. i was afraid of this, so this keeps me locked in to AWS for now. The sync command after 10 days does not ever finish because of the insane amount of objects.

Comment: Is this the sync to download, or to upload? Another method is to [Export Data from Amazon S3 with Snowball - AWS Snowball](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/snowball/latest/ug/create-export-job-steps.html), but then you'd have to upload from your own computer to Wasabi.

Comment: This is to sync 2 buckets for backup purposes.

Comment: If you wish to have a second copy of the data (well, Amazon S3 already keeps copies in 3 data centers, but if you want a copy in a _different location_), then you can use Amazon S3 [Cross-Region Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html) that will automatically copy the data to a different region (where it would again be kept in 3 different data centers).

Comment: It has to do with regulatory requirements, one should not only depend on only  one technical provider.

Answer (score 7):

There is this great open source tool "rclone" that can handle this.

It allows for sync between any two S3 compatible object stores - I used it for Minio to AWS S3

https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_sync/